# Getting the content of a .aspx file in a .cs class

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's a good method for getting the content of a .aspx web page as a `String`. This is from a C# Class which is compiled and deployed to the same machine.

Should I use a HTTP request? Or is there a means of doing the same through a file path, and would this trigger the code behind of the page?

Comment: The simplest way is probably doing a HTTP request yes.

Comment: You can get it via a file path. No, it wouldn't trigger the code behind. Doing an HTTP Request would give you the resulting HTML from the page execution.

Comment: Depends what you want. The rendered content or the content that is on the aspx page when you are developing it in VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use HTTP request, like `WebClient` and use `WebClient.DownloadString(@"http://someSite/somepage.aspx")`, that would trigger the server side code and you will get `HTML` generated by the server. Not the actual `aspx` page.

But if you use `File.ReadAllLines('somepage.aspx')` from your current project then you will get the file contents and it will not trigger the server side code. But you can only do that from your current project. You can't access an `aspx` page over `http`

Answer (score 1):

This code retrieves the root directory that is hosting the application in IIS. Then, it concatenates the filename. Finally, it reads the contents into a string variable.

Reading a file from disk does not trigger the code-behind; only a request through the ASP.NET pipeline does that.

```
string path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "Index.aspx");
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP request would usually not return the content of the aspx file since the server should interpret it (take this with a grain of salt, it all depends on your server and how its configured, maybe you've got a special setup)

If you want to read the content of the aspx file, open the file using its location on the disk. It won't trigger the code behind the page since this is triggered by the web server and you're not using it using a file path

if you want to read the output produced when the aspx file is read, open the url to this file. It will trigger the backing code and you will received the output.